# Phase-covariant unitaries

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, unitarity

A quantum channel $\Phi$ acting on an $n$-mode bosonic space is called phase-covariant if it commutes with the phase-shift operator, i.e. if $U_{\phi}\Phi(\rho)U_{\phi}^\dagger=\Phi(\rho)$ for any $\phi\in[0,2\pi)^{n}$ and $U_\phi=\bigoplus_{j=1}^n e^{-i\phi_j\hat N_j}$ where $\hat N_j$ is the number operator for the $j$-th mode.

My question is: under which conditions is a unitary channel $\Phi=\Phi_U$ phase-invariant? Are there any besides unitary phase-shifts?